# Delete folders whose name has 4 digit numbers two times

Tags: regular-expression

I want to delete folders using regexp in a Mac terminal.

```
0129_0140 (no delete)
0140_0140 (delete)
0150_0160 (no delete)
0170_0170 (delete)
```

I just want to delete folders such as 0140_0140 , 0170_0170 .

(Added)
I want to delete the nonempty folders, recursively.

Comment: does mac have gnu find ?

Comment: Yes, mac has the command find.

Comment: @123, all unix-likes have a `find` command, but the `find` on OS/X is not GNU `find`.

Comment: @123, for future reference, OSX man pages: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Non-recursive

With `ksh93` (on OS/X available as `ksh`):

```
rmdir {4}(\d)_\1
```

(beware it could delete a directory called `{4}(\d)_\1` if there's no file matching that pattern).

With `zsh` (on OS/X available as `zsh`):

```
setopt extendedglob
rmdir [0-9](#c4)_[0-9]##(/e:'[[ ${REPLY%_*} = ${REPLY#*_} ]]':)
```

(that one also has the benefit of only considering files of type *directory*, using the `/` glob qualifier above).

With `bash` or other POSIX shell (like the `sh` of most systems including `OS/X`):

```
set -- [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
for f do
  [ "${f#*_}" = "${f%_*}" ] && set -- "$@" "$f"
  shift
done
rmdir "$@"
```

(beware it could delete a directory called `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` if there are no `XXXX_XXXX` files in the current directory).

Using `find` and `grep`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' |
  grep -x '\./\(.*\)_\1' |
  xargs rmdir
```

With BSD `find` (as found on OS/X):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex './\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1' -type d -delete
```

With GNU `find` (as typically not found on OS/X unless installed via macports/homebrew/fink...):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype grep -regex './\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1' -type d -delete
```

### Recursively:

- `ksh93`:

  ```
  set -o globstar
  rmdir -- **/{4}(\d)\1
  ```

  (beware that it won't remove `1111_1111` in case there's a `1111_1111/2222_2222` as it will try to remove the `1111_1111` one first which it can't as there's a `2222_2222` dir in it, `ksh93` doesn't have the `od` glob qualifier (for depth-first order) of `zsh`)
- `zsh`:

  ```
  setopt extendedglob
  rmdir -- **/[0-9](#c4)_[0-9]##(Dod/e@'[[ ${${REPLY:t}%_*} = ${REPLY##*_} ]]'@)
  ```
- BSD `find`:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -regex '.*/\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1' -type d -delete
  ```
- GNU `find`:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -regextype grep -regex '.*/\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1' -type d -delete
  ```

Comment: The command doesn't work for me. I also tried 
find . -regex '{4}([0-9])_\1', but it also failed. Could you explain about the command?

Comment: Doesn't osx use bash (As default anyway) ?

Comment: @jakeoung, _shells_ are command line interpreters, the application that are usually started within terminal emulators like OS/X Terminal. By default terminal emulators usually start your login shell which by default on OS/X I believe is something like `tcsh` or `bash`. To start another shell, just enter its name at a shell prompt. `zsh` or `ksh` for instance. OS/X El Capitan at least has all of bash, zsh and ksh93 pre-installed.

Comment: Using find and grep works in default mode. Oh, I see. Many thanks.

Comment: But it doesn't work recursively. find . ! -name . -prune -type d -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' | grep -x '\./\(.*\)_\1' |   xargs rm -rf

Comment: @jakeoung, well you never said it had to be recursive, the `-prune` is to explicitely tell it not to recurse. Please edit your answer to add the information, also specify whether you want to delete the directory contents as well (if those directories may not be empty), and if dirs like `0001_0001/0002_0002` may exist.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Won't the directory's contents be deleted automatically when the top level directory is deleted ?

Comment: @123, not with `rmdir` which only removes directories, not their contents.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Where do the contents go then ?

Comment: @123, directories that are not empty cannot be removed obviously. See my comment for ksh93 in recursively

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yep just realised that, thanks :)

Comment: You forgot to mention `nullglob`.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX (remove `echo` from `echo rmdir` to actually erase the files) :

```
for dir in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/; do
    a="$(expr "$dir" : '\(.*\)_\1/')"
    ${a:+false} || echo rmdir "$dir"
done
```

Or:

```
for d in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/; do
    expr "$d" : '\(\(.*\)_\2\)/' >/dev/null && echo rmdir "$d"
done
```

Or:

```
set -- [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
for    d
do     expr "$d" : '\(\(.*\)_\2\)/' >/dev/null && echo rmdir "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./([0-9]{4})_\1' -delete
```

regex type setting is needed for the `{4}`.

Comment: Thats GNU find.

Comment: Note that POSIX extended regexps don't have backreferences, so that command might not work on all systems where GNU `find` is available if it's configured to use the system regexp library. Use posix-basic instead which has backreferences (also note that `\{4\}` was added to BRE before `{4}` was added to EREs (and broke backward portability when that happened which explains why the default regexps in GNU find don't support it for instance)).

Comment: A basic-regex is: `find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '\./\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1'`

Answer (score 1):

A pair of simple, POSIX-compliant alternatives:

Non-recursive (newlines disallowed in basename):

```
ls -F | grep '^\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1/$' | xargs rm -fr
```

Recursive:

```
find . -type d -exec expr {} : '.*/\([0-9]\{4\}\)_\1$' \; -prune \
       -exec rm -fr {} + >/dev/null
```